What is the reason for having Al Pacino’s line “¡Olvida! Matamos este tipo solo. Sin mujer, sin hijos” be in Spanish instead of English?
In Scarface (1983), what is the reason for having Al Pacino’s line “¡Olvida! Matamos este tipo solo. Sin mujer, sin hijos” be in Spanish instead of English?

In moments of stress people revert to their native language?
